# Group by two parameters and count in linq, considering occurrences of 0

Tags: c#, linq, count, group-by

I have an object objA of the type `IQueriable<EntityA>` and I want to make a query in c# using lambda notation, grouping by two parameters (Status and WeekOfYear), and counting the occurrences of each entity of type EntityA in objA. And I want the result set to have counts of 0.

```
IQueriable<EntityA> objA= ...

var group = objA.GroupBy(a => new { a.Status, a.WeekOfYear })
                .Select(a => new { a.Key.Status, a.Key.Week, Count = a.Count() });
```

The above code is the closest I get from what I want. It returns `IQueriable<int, int, int>`, which I can easily insert into my excel table. But I don't get an entrance in the result set when the count is 0, and then it gets tricky to fill the Excel sheet. Is it possible to obtain the result I require, or do I really have to check all the pairs (so inelegant!!!)?

Comment: Where do you have all the combinations of *Status x WeekOfYear*? Normally you would left-join them to your data and then count in some way...

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Distinct()` function,
you can get all statuses and all WeekOfYear and check count for every tuple.

Code is like this and you can get a working demo in [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GHzYhP)

```
using System;   
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IQueryable<Entity> data = (new List<Entity>() {
            new Entity { Status = "1", Week = "a"},
                new Entity { Status = "2", Week = "c"},
                new Entity { Status = "3", Week = "b"},
                new Entity { Status = "1", Week = "a"},
                new Entity { Status = "1", Week = "a"}  
        }) .AsQueryable();;



        var result = new List<EntityResult>();

        var statuses = data.Select(a => a.Status).Distinct().ToList();
        var weeks = data.Select(a => a.Week).Distinct().ToList();

        statuses.ForEach(s => {
            weeks.ForEach( w => {
                int count = data.Where(a => a.Status == s && a.Week == w).Count();

                result.Add(new EntityResult { Status = s, Week = s, Count= count});
            });
        });


        Console.WriteLine(result[0].Count);
    }



}

public class Entity 
{
    public string Status;

    public string Week;
}

public class EntityResult
{

    public string Status;

    public string Week;

    public int Count;
}
```

Comment: What if not all status/week combinations are present in the data?

Comment: It will insert a record with count 0

Comment: No, I mean, suppose there is an entry `Status = "5", Week = "a"`. There won't be interpolated counts 0 for status `4`. That's what I understand the OP tries to achieve.

Comment: If you have a list with all possible weeks you can use it instead of distinct values

Comment: I'm not the asker :) Someone already proposed that, but OP doesn't respond.